# How to create HTTP server push (also known as HTTP streaming) with PHP?

Tags: php, http, streaming, push

How to create HTTP server push (also known as HTTP streaming) with PHP (better streaming video)?

Tuts
Libs
are vary welcome

Comment: What are you trying to stream? Do you have some kind of output from PHP you are trying to send, or are you actually trying to stream video/audio? "push" and "streaming" are two different concepts, though they can be related. Push generally refers to content being updated in a browser automatically, and there are many ways to implement it. Streaming is sending a continuous feed of content, and showing it to the client in near-real-time (eg, video).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know about streaming video and comet. I know that streaming video uses more protocols in order to keep and open connection and support frame loss.

You can use libraries, so use google as your search tool. If you don't want to use the comet server and want comet LIKE behavior using plain old php, you can check the following article: http://www.zeitoun.net/articles/comet_and_php/start

Sorry i haven't use any library so i cannot recommend anything in my post.